# Tweet Button - hiding zero count

Tags: twitter, button, social-networking

I'm interested in adding to some of my sites the official [Tweet button](http://twitter.com/goodies/tweetbutton) which Twitter have recently released.

For those unaware, the tweet button is a simple bit of JS which you can drop in to a page and it allows your users to easily tweet about the page in question, much like the facebok "share" button.

There are 3 different styles available:

[image: Tweet button styles]

The horizontal count button is the one I'd like to put on my pages. My problem is that roughly half of my pages are likely to have a zero count, and I'd rather not show the count when this is the case. The facebook share button, for example, handles this particular situation well - if there are > 0 shares, then it shows the count. Otherwise the count stays hidden.

I've gone through the twitter docs, and can't seem to find a way of specifying this in the JS parameters.

I also spent some time trying to capture the count via jquery and hide it, but quickly ran in to cross-domain permission issues -

```
console.log($('.twitter-share-button').contents().html());
```

returns a `Permission denied` error due to the iframe being loaded from `platform0.twitter.com`.

Has anyone yet found a successful way to get this button to conditionally show the tweet counts as described above?

Comment: Guess this would be easy when Twitter makes the Tweet button count-api public. 
http://dev.twitter.com/pages/tweet_button_faq#count-api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A google search later, found http://ottopress.com/2010/twitters-new-tweet-button-and-the-count-api/ which talks about how to use the count api `http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=URL-TO-GET-COUNT-FOR`.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant solution, but you could always stagger the release of the different button types.

Eg, show the 'no count' button initially, then display the 'horiztonal count' say, a week from the publication date.  (i'm making the assumption you're running some type of blog)

Again, not great, but it partially solves your problem - you'll display the 'zero tweets' button less often.

Regards
Luke